# Compare two columns of same row SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table sample that looks like :

```
KeyID   Name    ID    Location  
--------------------------------------------
20063   A DA    20439     AEP  DA           
20063   A DA    20063     APS DA            
20063   A DA    20032     APS RT          
20063   A RT    20032     APS RT          
20063   B RT    20032     APS DA Legacy
```

Only select rows where `Name` and `Location` both ends with either `DA` or `RT`.

Exception: if location ends with legacy , include row regardless.

```
          20063 A DA    20439     AEP  DA           
          20063 A DA    20063     APS DA    
          20063 A RT    20032     APS RT
          20063 B RT    20032     APS DA Legacy
```

How do I compare column of same row for this SQL?

Comment: Is it always the last 2 letters?

Comment: Yes. Always the last 2 letters.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work in MySQL, but most likely in other SQLs too:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE location like '% Legacy'
    OR (
        SUBSTRING(name,-2)='DA' AND SUBSTRING(location,-2)='DA'
        OR
        SUBSTRING(name,-2)='RT' AND SUBSTRING(location,-2)='RT'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

if using Microsoft SQL you may have to do something like this.  You reverse the string, pull the first 2 characters using substring from the first character with a length of 2, then reverse it again to put it back the right way.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE location like '% Legacy'
     OR
     (
            reverse(substring(reverse(name),1,2))='DA' 
            AND 
            reverse(substring(reverse(location),1,2))='DA'
        OR
            reverse(substring(reverse(name),1,2))='RT' 
            AND 
            reverse(substring(reverse(location),1,2))='RT'
     )
```